# PayPal Express Checkout Page with details (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, express-checkout

I have a problem with PayPal classic API (for .net):

I want to show the details of the object during the express checkout process (PayPal). I used the classic API (.net) and I populated all the parameters (name, details ecc) before call "SetExpressCheckout(passing SetExpressCheckoutReq with element SetExpressCheckoutRequestType -> SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType with details)" of "PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService".

Usually paypal show me this page (I also set &useraction=commit) [KO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqIsl.png) but I want this! [OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tDVA.png)

I also try to pass some parameter into query string to paypal (without success)

`PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.05&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=1.05&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Account+PRO+2&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.05`

Is it possible to set a paypal description page?

Thanks

Comment: Resolved (Partially) - I forgot to add description also in  paymentDetails. 

paymentDetails0.PaymentDetailsItem = new List<PaymentDetailsItemType>() {
                    new PaymentDetailsItemType() {
                        Amount = new BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, howMuchS),
                        Description = descr,
                        Name = itemName,
                        Quantity = 1
                    }
                };

Comment: Your last comment should have resolved your question....